# What is the VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable used for

Tags: python, virtualenv

Reading Python's `virtualenv/bin/activate` script, I noticed that besides the obvious manipulation of the `PATH` variable, it also sets and exports `VIRTUAL_ENV`. I wonder is this significant, and who or what uses this variable?

I'm asking because I assumed that you can instead of using the `activate` script also do something like:

```bash
$ venv/bin/python3 ...
```

or

```bash
$ venv/bin/flake8
```

to explicitly use the virtual environment for one-shot commands or in makefiles. Now I realize that it is not quite equivalent as the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable would be missing.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer in [the docs for venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv):

> When a virtual environment is active, the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable is set to the path of the virtual environment. **This can be used to check if one is running inside a virtual environment.**

further:

> **You don’t specifically need to activate an environment; activation just prepends the virtual environment’s binary directory to your path**, so that “python” invokes the virtual environment’s Python interpreter and you can run installed scripts without having to use their full path. However, all scripts installed in a virtual environment should be runnable without activating it, and run with the virtual environment’s Python automatically.

So according to the docs, you don't have to activate the venv, but then you don't have the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable set. This implies that the `VIRTUAL_ENV` is not a very reliable way of checking if you're running inside a venv.

Answer (score 2):

[People use it for anything](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22VIRTUAL_ENV%22+%22environment+variable%22), primary to detect if a virtualenv is activated at all; sometimes to find out its directory. Almost nobody needs it for a one-shot command because the environment kinda activated and deactivated immediately.

I use it to deactivate [temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+mktmpenv) environments created by virtualenvwrapper's `mktmpenv` in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Clean up python virtual environment on exit
# See https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#clean-up-environments-on-exit

trap '[ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ] && deactivate' EXIT
```

Deactivated temporary environments are automatically self-destroyed and deleted from disk.

I also use it to re-activate a virtualenv in a subshell that inherited the variable from its parent shell:

```
if [ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ] && ! type deactivate >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    . "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate"
fi
```